# Django 2.1 View Permission

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-permissions

The [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.default_permissions) states that the new View Permission is added to Django 2.1 but without further clarifications on how this will be used especially on the Django Admin Site.

It is my understanding this will be kind of ReadOnly Permission, but I will appreciate more clarifications from any one with better understanding on this new permission and its  behavior on the Admin Site

Comment: the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.1/) link to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **correct**. The [Django 2.1 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.1/#model-view-permission) describe this change:

> **Model "view" permission**
>
> A "view" permission is added to the model `Meta.default_permissions`.
>   The new permissions will be created automatically when running
>   migrate.
>
> This allows **giving users read-only access to models in the admin**.
>   [**`ModelAdmin.has_view_permission()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission) is new. The implementation is
>   backwards compatible in that there isn’t a need to assign the "view"
>   permission to allow users who have the "change" permission to edit
>   objects.

Furthermore the documentation for [**`ModelAdmin.has_view_permission`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission) permission explains it like:

> **`ModelAdmin.has_view_permission(request, obj=None)`**
>
> Should return `True` if **viewing `obj` is permitted**, `False`
>   otherwise. If `obj` is `None`, should return `True` or `False` to
>   indicate whether viewing of objects of this type is permitted in
>   general (e.g., `False` will be interpreted as meaning that the current
>   user is not permitted to view any object of this type).
>
> The **default implementation returns `True` if the user has either the
>   "change" or "view" permission**.

So in this case, the "change" permission implies the "view" permission (which is rather logical, since it would be strange to change an object, without being able to see it first).

Comment: Thanks for these details, it was helpful enough

Answer (score 0):

You are right they didn't clarify on how to use it, but I found out how to use it. By default, the view permission will return true, so its only use case is if you want to prevent users from viewing the admin object. And this is how you can do it.

```
class ViewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```